# How to get value from database to create dynamic names for inputs in looped form?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, input

I'm working on a website using HTML, Python, SQL and Flask, and I've come across a problem since in one part I want to include a quiz using data from a table called flashcards in a database, which includes these columns:

id_flashcard (INT) | language (TEXT) | word (TEXT) | definition (TEXT) | user_id (INT)

---

**edit:** database structure users.db

**[Table] flashcards**

```
id_flashcard (INT) | language (TEXT) | word (TEXT) | definition (TEXT) | user_id (INT)
```

---

```
    1          |     Italian     |  il gatto   |     the cat       |      2
```

**[Table] languages**

```
language (TEXT)    | flashcards (INT)|  quiz (INT) |   average (REAL)  | user_id (INT)
```

---

```
  Italian      |        1        |       0     |        0.0        |      2
```

**[Table] quizzes**

```
user_id (INT) | language (TEXT) | n_flashcards (INT)| correct_answers (INT) | avg_quiz (REAL) |  date (DATETIME)
```

**[Table] users**

```
id (INT)      |  username (TEXT) | hash (TEXT)
```

---

To make this quiz happen I looped over a form that takes all the cards needed for the quiz (in a previous page the user could choose the language), displaying the definition and letting the user write down the correct "word".
Now, my first problem is that I need to be able to give some kind of identifiers to each input, so that I can retrieve the answers once submitted.

This is what I have after numerous tries:

HTML form:

```
<form action="/quiztab" method="post">
   {% for card in db_user %}
   <div class="form-group row roundform">
       <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label" name="def_quiz[{{ card['id_flashcard'] }}]">{{ card["definition"] }}</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control roundform" type="text" name="answer[{{ card['id_flashcard'] }}]" placeholder="Write here the correct translation!">
       </div>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   <button class="roundbutton mt-5" type="submit">Give me the results!</button>
</form>
```

Application:

```
def quiztab():
    quiz_language = session.get('quiz_language', None)
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    overview_languages = db.execute("SELECT * FROM languages WHERE user_id = :user_id", user_id = user_id)
    db_user = db.execute("SELECT * FROM flashcards WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)
    cards = db.execute("SELECT word, definition FROM flashcards WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)
    n_cards = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM flashcards WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)[0]["count"]
    id_flashcards = db.execute("SELECT id_flashcard FROM flashcards WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)

    answer = []
    def_quiz = []

    if request.method == "POST":
       answer.append(request.form.get("answer[{{ card['id_flashcard'] }}]"))
       def_quiz.append(request.form.get("def_quiz[{{ card['id_flashcard'] }}]"))

       results = 0

       for x in answer:
          for y in def_quiz:
             correct_word = db.execute("SELECT word FROM flashcards WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language AND definition = :definition", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language, definition = def_quiz)
             if correct_word == answer:
                results = results + 1
             else:
                results = results

       add_quiz = db.execute("UPDATE languages SET quiz = quiz + 1 WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)
       avg = ((results / n_cards) * 100)
       update_quizzes = db.execute("INSERT INTO quizzes (user_id, language, n_flashcards, correct_answers, avg_quiz) VALUES (:user_id, :language, :n_flashcards, :correct_answers, :avg)", user_id = user_id, language = quiz_language, n_flashcards = n_cards, correct_answers = results, avg = avg)

       answer = []
       def_quiz = []
       return redirect("/quiz")

    else:
       return render_template("quiztab.html", db_user = db_user, id_flashcards = id_flashcards)
```

Unfortunately, it is still impossible for me to get the inputs and basically check if they're correct or not and since I am still a beginner I find myself not having a clue how to solve and approach this.

Any help is deeply appreciated :)

Comment: Can you add to your question the model of your database and if possible the example of a record in the languages and flashcards tables?

Comment: What is actually working so far?  Can you render the quiztab?  Can you submit anything?

Comment: With GET quiztab renders and everything seems to work, but as soon as I submit the form, so the method changes to POST, even if I get correctly redirected back to /quiz I can't get the inputs of the form ("answer" and "def_answer" in application). I think the problematic part is when I try getting all the inputs from the form, so in the HTML the way I try to get a kind of identification and in the application the "request.form.get".

Answer (score 0):

As I could not reproduce all your code, I provide here a minimal example from which you can draw inspiration

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/home", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # Suppose that after the sql request the data is in this form
    quiz = [{'id': 1, 'def_quiz': 'il gato', 'answer': 'the cat'},
            {'id': 2, 'def_quiz': 'il cane', 'answer': 'the dog'}]

    if request.method == "POST":

        # I convert the form's data to dictionary
        data = request.form.to_dict()

        # this gives me a dictionary of the form {'def_quiz_id': 'answer_typed'}
        # {'1': 'the cat', '2': 'the dog'}
        print(data)
        result = 0

        for def_quiz, answer in data.items():
            print(def_quiz, answer)
            # replace this line with your sql request
            recorded_answer = [q for q in quiz if q['id'] == int(def_quiz)][0]['answer']
            print("the answer recorded", recorded_answer)
            if recorded_answer == answer:
                result += 1
        print("result: ", result)

        # the rest of your code here...
        
    return render_template('home.html', quiz=quiz)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

templates/home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="/home" method="post">
   {% for q in quiz %}
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>{{ q["def_quiz"] }}</label>
       <div>
           <input type="text" name="{{ q['id'] }}" placeholder="Write here the correct translation!">
       </div>
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   <button type="submit">Give me the results!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Tobin, I'll try this out! I'm just wondering, for "quiz" in app.py you mean my variable "db_user"?

Comment: There is still a problem with this part:
for definition, answer in data.items():
            recorded_answer = [q for q in db_user if q['id_flashcard'] == int(definition)][0]['answer']
            print("the answer recorded", recorded_answer)
            if recorded_answer == answer:
                result += 1

KeyError: 'answer'

Comment: can you update your answer so that i can see precisely what is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went for this approach. Of course everything can maybe be more elegant but for now this worked out for me:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.form.to_dict()

    result = 0

    for x in range(len(data)):

        check1 = int(list(data.keys())[x])
        check2 = quiz[x]['id_flashcard']
        check3 = list(data.values())[x]
        check4 = quiz[x]['word']

        if check1 == check2 and check3 == check4:
            result += 1

    add_quiz = db.execute("UPDATE languages SET quiz = quiz + 1 WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)
    avg = ((result / n_cards) * 100)
    update_quizzes = db.execute("INSERT INTO quizzes (user_id, language, n_flashcards, correct_answers, avg_quiz) VALUES (:user_id, :language, :n_flashcards, :correct_answers, :avg)", user_id = user_id, language = quiz_language, n_flashcards = n_cards, correct_answers = result, avg = avg)
    sum_avg_quizzes = db.execute("SELECT SUM(avg_quiz) as sum FROM quizzes WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)[0]["sum"]
    quiz_n = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM quizzes WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)[0]["count"]
    tot_avg_quizzes = sum_avg_quizzes / quiz_n
    update_avg_quiz = db.execute("UPDATE languages SET average = :average WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language = :quiz_language", average = tot_avg_quizzes, user_id = user_id, quiz_language = quiz_language)

    return redirect("/quiz")
```

Thank you for the help! :)